# Angular2 Final: Error inline template: is not a valid digit info for number pipes

Tags: angular

### Code

```
 <h2>{{totalTargetValue | currency:'EUR':true:'2'}}</h2>
```

### Error

Error inline template: is not a valid digit info for number pipes

Any idea how to solve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not passing valid value to `digitInfo`. This is required format for `CurrencyPipe`:

```
number_expression | currency[:currencyCode[:symbolDisplay[:digitInfo]]]
```

`digitInfo` requires format that looks like this:

```
{minIntegerDigits}.{minFractionDigits}-{maxFractionDigits}
```

It is also used for `DecimalPipe`, you can read more about it [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/DecimalPipe-pipe.html).

So, instead of `2`, it could be `1.2-2` for example:

```
<h2>{{totalTargetValue | currency:'EUR':true:'1.2-2'}}</h2>
```

Read more about `CurrencyPipe` [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/CurrencyPipe-pipe.html).